# How to use Paths(java.nio.file.Paths) in nashorn javascript

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have a path (eg: `"C:/Users/aaa/bbb/ccc/"`), my aim to get the parent path (i.e. `"C:/Users/aaa/bbb/"`)

For this I tried using `java.nio.file.Paths`, which worked in java and I tried converting the same into nashorn js:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class ReadPropertiesFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String myPath = "C:/Users/aaa/bbb/ccc/";
            System.out.println(Paths.get(myPath).getParent());
    }
}
```

Nashorn script:

```
var testPath = "C:/Users/aaa/bbb/ccc/";
var Paths = java.import("java.nio.file.Paths");
try{
    var test = Paths.get(testPath).getParent();
                            console.log("++++++MyFINALPATH+++++"+test); 
}catch (e){                         console.log("++++++MyFINALPATH+++++"+e);
}
```

Expected output: `C:/Users/aaa/bbb/`

> Error-
>   TypeError: Paths.get(...).getParent is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this instead:

```
var Paths = Java.type("java.nio.file.Paths");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/scripting/using-java-scripts.htm#JSJSG117